# decorations.text: How to have math inside the text key?

Tags: pgfplots, decorations

How to fix the following to have math inside the `text` key with dynamic variables?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, math, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\adhesion}{5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            cycle list name = color list,
            ]
            %
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, 2}{
                \addplot+ [
                    variable = \Fbr,
                    postaction = {
                        decoration = {
                            text along path,
                            text = {$\mu = #1 + \adhesion$},
                            }, decorate,
                        },
                    ]
                {#1 - \Fbr};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa I am not. However, it is my guess since just `$\mu$` gets me the same error.

Comment: @campa I forgot to load the relevant libraries. So, I will delete or edit the question to post it correctly.

Comment: `text along path={hello}` makes a box out of each letter. This is not possible with a math formula.

Comment: @Diaa If your math does not get any more complicate, you could set your label as normal text, e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i56g.png (the spacing is off, but at least you would have a label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but enclosing the math in `{$ $}` and adding empty `{}` after it did the trick and made me able to parse a complete math input.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, math, intersections}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\adhesion}{5}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            cycle list name = color list,
            ]
            %
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1, 2}{
                \addplot+ [
                    variable = \Fbr,
                    postaction = {
                        decoration = {
                            text along path,
                            text = {$\mu = #1 + \adhesion \sqrt{\theta}$}{},
                            }, decorate,
                        },
                    ]
                {#1 - \Fbr};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have an entire math formula along a path. In this case you can get an approximation by doing

```
text = {{$\mu$} = \adhesion{} + #1},
```

With just two cycles, in order to reduce the ugliness:

[image]

Of course your paths will be different and the positioning so there's no overlap, I guess.

Comment: Why does the simple case `text = {{$\mu$}},` fail?
Should be there any normal text as in `text = {{$\mu$}{}},`? Edit: I just found out that an entire math can be employed by just having `{}` at the end like `text = {{$\mu = \sqrt{\theta}$}{}},`.

Comment: @Diaa `text along path` is difficult. Are you sure that the math formula works along a *curved* path?

Comment: For now, I haven't needed to do so or try it.